# How to have properly formatted json string with one space after comma using gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

In my below code, I am making a json string using gson:

```
private String generateData(Map<String, Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>> nodeTable, int i) {
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

    Set<Integer> pp = nodeTable.get("TEXTER").get(i);
    Set<Integer> sp = nodeTable.get("PETER").get(i);

    // my above pp and sp variables shows correct values with one space between numbers.

    jsonObject.addProperty("description", "Hello. World");
    jsonObject.add("data1", gson.toJsonTree(pp));
    jsonObject.add("data2", gson.toJsonTree(sp));

    System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());

    return jsonObject.toString();
}
```

When I get my json string, I get it like this. As you can see after comma everything is next to each other without any spaces. I don't want like that.

```
{"description":"Hello. World.","data1":[0,273,546,819,1092,559],"data2":[816,1644,1368,276]}
```

I want my json string to be like this: Meaning after comma there should be one space so it should look like below.

```
{"description":"Hello. World.", "data1":[0, 273, 546, 819, 1092, 559], "data2":[816, 1644, 1368, 276]}
```

How can I do this?

**Update:-**

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
private String generateData(Map<String, Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>> nodeTable, int i) {

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder = gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting();   //Sets pretty formatting
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();       

    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

    Set<Integer> pp = nodeTable.get("TEXTER").get(i);
    Set<Integer> sp = nodeTable.get("PETER").get(i);

    // my above pp and sp variables shows correct values with one space between numbers.

    jsonObject.addProperty("description", "Hello. World");
    jsonObject.add("data1", gson.toJsonTree(pp));
    jsonObject.add("data2", gson.toJsonTree(sp));

    System.out.println(gson.toJson(jsonObject));

    return gson.toJson(jsonObject);
}
```

Comment: The json file does not expect spaces (or any other character) outside of `"`, can you give details on why you need this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON string should not include unwanted whites paces because in most of the cases *it is the medium to transport data*, otherwise it will add bandwidth cost(may be small but considered) and also parsing white spaces in client side.

But still if you format it to print pretty or to look readable, you can make use of [GsonBuilder](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setPrettyPrinting()) to set it as shown below

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder = gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting();   //Sets pretty formatting
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();                //Create Gson reference

System.out.println(gson.toJson(object));        //prints in pretty format
```

Output:

```
{
  "a": 5,
  "name": "Hello.world.",
  "someOtherString": "some other string"
}
```

---

Updated question:

I'm not sure the method parameter's type, so in below sample program I used string, so it did work. I suggest you to change from  `jsonObject.add("data1", gson.toJsonTree(pp));` to `jsonObject.addProperty("data1", gson.toJson(pp));`. This may solve, let me know.

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder = gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting();   //Sets pretty formatting
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();                //Create Gson reference

JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.addProperty("description", "Hello. World");
jsonObject.addProperty("asfaf", "New. World");
jsonObject.addProperty("asfa", "Old. World");

System.out.println(gson.toJson(jsonObject));
```

Output

```
{
  "description": "Hello. World",
  "asfaf": "New. World",
  "asfa": "Old. World"
}
```

Comment: In my case everything is going to same and I am just going to add first three lines to use GsonBuilder and then at the end use it like this `gson.toJson(jsonObject)`?

Comment: I have updated my question. I just tried with that code but it doesn't work? Any idea what wrong I am doinng?

Comment: I am going to try this out now but for simple test you can have two sets with some values in it and see whether that works for you.

Comment: It is adding `\n` somehow to the output.